# I would like to connect two discrete NIC in one computer

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have a system with two discrete NIC, therby, I have two discrete network on my window client. How are clients on network 1 able to see the clients that sitting on network 2? I hope I have been able to convey my meaning

Comment: if you run a traceroute on one client on network 1 to a client on network 2 - it'll tell you

Comment: This really depends on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to hook 1 computer to 2 existing networks so it can see both, or are you trying to connect the 2 networks together?  (Also,  are the networks on different IP ranges)

Comment: I am trying to connect two networks together. for example, my wireless smart phone  that reside on network 1  through Wi-Fi could see another computer that reside on the network 2.

Comment: If you want this for combining the two bandwidths, it won't work on a Windows client.